# In app billing supported countries for android

Tags: android, google-play

I just want to confirm that in app billing for Android will work in all the countries which are able to purchase paid apps? e.g. India

Answer (score 5):

[Verifying that in-app billing is supported (CHECK_BILLING_SUPPPORTED)](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html) Run the code and test it.

Check the [list of supported merchants](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324&topic=15867&ctx=topic) (Google Blog)

See the [Complete list of **Free & Paid** app distribution country wise](https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138294)

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are all the countries directly supported

Argentina, 
Australia, 
Austria, 
Belgium, 
Brazil, 
Bulgaria, 
Cameroon, 
Canada, 
Côte d’Ivoire, 
Cyprus, 
Czech Republic, 
Denmark, 
Estonia, 
Finland, 
France, 
Germany, 
Ghana, 
Greece, 
Hong Kong, 
Hungary, 
Iceland, 
India, 
Ireland, 
Israel, 
Italy, 
Japan, 
Kenya, 
Latvia, 
Lithuania, 
Luxembourg, 
Malta, 
Mexico, 
Netherlands, 
New Zealand, 
Nicaragua, 
Norway, 
Philippines, 
Poland, 
Portugal, 
Romania, 
Russia, 
Senegal, 
Singapore, 
Slovakia, 
Slovenia, 
South Africa, 
South Korea, 
Spain, 
Sweden, 
Switzerland, 
Taiwan, 
Thailand, 
Ukraine, 
United Kingdom, 
United States

I'm pretty sure tho that if they have a currency they will be supported, those are just the ones im definite on

Comment: Its a bad idea to post this list as it changes quite often, better to link to Google's own website and let them handle the changes.

Comment: didn't know of any list with the list of countries at the time, still dont?